# Non-bootable Win 2003 Server--need to find ODBC settings

Tags: windows-7, regedit, windows-2003-webserver

I inherited a problem.  I have a Windows 2003 machine that will not boot.  I really just need to view the ODBC setttings from this drive (i.e. win 2003 boot drive).  I was able to mount and access the drive from Win 7.

My plan was to:
1. Launch regedit from Win 7
2. Use Load Hive to access registry on 2003 drive.
3. Find ODBC setting information.

However, Win 7's regedit will not let me use load hive.  It's disabled.

How can I enable load hive? Will load hive allow me to access the win 2003's registry?  Is there an easier way to vview the ODBC settings?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow instructions [here](http://smallvoid.com/article/winnt-offline-registry-edit.html). You can only load onto HKLM (local machine) in win7.

Comment: Thanks Sajid!  Instructions allowed me to load hive from 2003 boot disk and find all ODBC settings.